# Roger-Router: Cannot set file owner for /var/spool/roger/userName: Operation not permitted

Tags: router, fax, fritzbox, efax

I installed Roger-router on my Linux Mint Debian Edition 64Bit.
I had it running before on the same system on a different HDD. Now if I try to send a fax with printing it to the roger-router-printer, I get this error message:

```
Angehalten - Cannot set file owner for /var/spool/roger/userName: Operation not permitted
```

Angehalten is german for 'stopped'. userName is my username.

I searched the internet for many hours now, but couldn't manage to get it running. Does anyone of you has any idea what could be the problem here?

I would appreciate it a lot!
Thanks.

Comment: Which user account are you using, and is it member of the fax group? Which version of Roger-router and where did you get it?

Comment: @harrymc I am using 'userName' like in the error message. It is member of the fax group. I use the version 1.8.9-2jessie1. I think I installed it from the normal packet sources.

Comment: I think this is a [known bug](http://osdir.com/ml/general/2015-09/msg13073.html) in version 1.8.9-2, but check your file permissions. I think [version 1.9.2](https://www.tabos.org/) is now out, but I unfortunately don't read German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a known bug in version 1.8.9-2. See the bug report
[Bug#798471: roger-router: "Cannot set file owner for /var/spool/roger/" when using fax printer](http://osdir.com/ml/general/2015-09/msg13073.html).

Check if any file permissions are insufficient, in case this is just an
installation issue.

I believe that [Roger Router version 1.9.2](https://www.tabos.org/) is now out, but
the website is in German which I don't read.